# What are you specifically automating in UI test automation?

Tags: testing, architecture, selenium, automation

All the documents I have read so far on various testing frameworks (Selenium, Tellurium, Canoo etc)  encourage (or at least concentrate) on functional testing an application through UI. I have seen very less on the below which I believe are most important ones

1. localization testing
2. usability testing
3. cross browser compatibility testing
4. testing against multiple versions of the same browser
5. xss/sql injection
6. validation
7. Is the UI/presentation layer calling the correct service layer API (service layer being tested thoroughly through component based testing)

So here are my questions

1) What are you specifically automating in UI test automation?

2) Which UI testing framework can meet all the above items?

Comment: can the gentleman explain why this was voted to be closed?

Comment: its argumentative 'What does UI testing mean to you?" ,'Which framework is best" come on really ?

Comment: alright now the question is very specific. tx

Comment: wouldn't this be better suited for community wiki or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Selenium in the past and it works great for all of the 1-7 except maybe localization since I did not have to test that. As 2, the applications I have tested were mostly just "write something in textbox and see if it works", so it was quite easy. And, for 4, I had multiple virtual machines with only specific browsers installed. It was hackjob, but, worked, sort of.

Comment: may be argumentative but I am seeking suggestions.

Comment: can you explain how you tested 2, 4 and 5 with selenium pls

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand what you mean by <img src ="">

Comment: Nothing, just to fulfill the character limit. Also, please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Automation projects till now is not that mature to incorporate all the points you mentioned. Majority cases automation is used to test functionality through UI. Also backed up with unit testing to have more coverage on Functional part.

Framework, there will not be any ready to use framework available. But there are tools which has these capabilities, like eggPlant (TestPlant). Generally industry follows is hybrid kind of automation. Like use jmeter to fire number of REST calls and check response. Which will cover client-server calls. And use selenium kind of tool, to check Client UI.

For Cross browser, cross platforms Selenium Grid with junit framework can be formed easily.